# Read incoming notifications in real-time android

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcast

I'm trying to read all incoming notifications in a text view...

I want to look something like this

I found some codes, but all mixed up and does not work, any help will be very appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**It will work from: Android 4.3 (JELLY_BEAN_MR2).**

1. Add to your manifest new permission `android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE`.
2. Create NotificationListenerService class and add to the manifest.
   From Google Developer:

> Must be required by an NotificationListenerService, to ensure that
>   only the system can bind to it.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
         android:label="@string/service_name"
      android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

3. Override the `onNotificationPosted()`.

NotificationListenerService Class:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public class NotificationListenerService extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(final StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
// Here you need to play with the sbn object and get the data that you want from it.

        //sbn.getPackageName()
        Notification notification = sbn.getNotification();
        Bundle extras = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            extras = notification.extras;
        }

        if (extras != null) {
            extras.get("android.title");
        }
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    }

    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void onListenerDisconnected() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            // Notification listener disconnected - requesting rebind
            requestRebind(new ComponentName(this, NotificationListenerService2.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Developer reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

Simple example application for implementation: https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example/